# websphere server FileNotFoundException for a simple J2EE application

Tags: websphere, ibm-rad

I got `FileNotFoundException` while running a very basic J2EE application.
I am using IBM RAD and websphere.

> java.io.FileNotFoundException: JSPG0036E: Failed to find resource /test/hello.jsp

```
    at com.ibm.ws.jsp.webcontainerext.AbstractJSPExtensionProcessor.findWrapper(AbstractJSPExtensionProcessor.java:293)


    at com.ibm.ws.jsp.webcontainerext.AbstractJSPExtensionProcessor.handleRequest(AbstractJSPExtensionProcessor.java:266)


    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:3129)
```

Any idea regarding this isuue?

Comment: So you're trying to hit a version of WebSphere which is running within RAD, correct? What port are you hitting, and are you hitting the correct context-root of the web application?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if the information you provided is sufficient enough, what do  you mean by running the web project? Are you hitting the url /test/hello.jsp? have you checked if this file is present in you application war/ear ( and in the correct location i.e. web content folder) ? Can you check wether you deployment is sucessful by going to the WAS web console and checking the application status?

Comment: I have just installed IBM rad and trying to test that wheather J2EE application is working properly.

Comment: I have just installed IBM rad and trying to test that wheather J2EE application is working properly.
For which I have created a sample web project.
I have checked everything,
jsp file is there,deployment is successful,
but still I'm getting FileNotFoundException